# Can´t save my uploaded file with <> in the name? (error: failed to open stream: Invalid argument)

Tags: php

Im uploading files with sucess, but now Im trying to save my file name with <> and its not working.

I´m getting this error: **failed to open stream: Invalid argument.**

Like this **works** fine:

```
$f['pdf'] = $f['title'].'+TO+'.$name_em.'+FROM+'.$name_recp.'.'.$ext;
```

Like this **dont works**: (with <> <>)

```
$f['pdf'] = $f['title'].'<TO>'.$name_em.'<FROM>'.$name_recp.'.'.$ext;
```

I tried also like this: ( but dont works also)

```
 $f['pdf'] = $f['title'].'<'.'FROM'.'>'.$name_em.'<TO>'.$name_recp.'.'.$ext;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dagon, but dont works also with double quote!

Comment: Where are you attempting to save it? I don't see any of that code here.

Comment: @OzzC: Yeah, they're not legal characters either! Instead of guessing, go look up the list of valid path characters for your platform.

Comment: Well, I dont understand downvote, I didnt put all code here because I think its not necessary, Im just having this problem, the upload works fine if I dont use <>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<> are not allowed in filenames e.g. on windows-Systems.

Comment: Thank you user3132781, I dint know that, so I'll use my '+'. Thanks!